# how do I toggle 'solo' and 'mute' from script (animator)

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image](unity animator)

I'm trying to toggle solo and mute on a transition from anystate to my weapon attack animations (there are multiple because I need an animation for moving whilst attacking) and I need to toggle solo and/or mute in certain situations. how do you toggle them outside of the inspecter (so instead toggling solo and mute with code), or is it not possible. if it isn't possible, what situations are solo and mute used for?

Comment: Can you show us the animation graph please?

Comment: ok just a second

Comment: I want to unmute the muted ones in an if statement or something

Comment: As far as i know solo and mute are there to isolate the parts of the graph for mostly for test. You could try to do your states differently. Perhaps with blend trees or some int parameters.